# In Java 8, is there a way to map a function over two streams?

Tags: java, java-8, mapping, java-stream

I have two streams, say:

```
final Stream<Integer> firstStream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
final Stream<Integer> secondStream = Stream.of(10, 20, 30);
```

I want to combine the streams by adding the pairwise elements, as if I wrote

```
Streams.map(
    (item1, item2) -> item1 + item2,
    firstStream,
    secondStream);
```

And get as the result a stream equivalent to:

```
Streams.of(11, 22, 33);
```

Is there a built-in method to do this? I could roll my own with a `while` or `for` loop, but I'm using Java 8 and would prefer to use something simpler.

Note that the process I want to do is not simply adding the elements, but is a more complex function. But this should be a good example of what I want to do.

Comment: Stream<Integer> s1 = Stream.of(1,2,3);
   Stream<Integer> s2 = Stream.of(10,20,30);
   Iterator<Integer> i1 = s1.iterator();
   Iterator<Integer> i2 = s2.iterator();
   Stream<Integer> s = Stream.generate(()-> i1.next()+i2.next()).limit(3);
   s.forEach(System.out::println);